# Customize vue-multiselect options and label

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-multiselect

By default, when we use vue-multiselect, the provided options only appear as it is in the selected labels. I want to customize this.

Support, I have this as the data,

```
options: [
  { code: 1002, text: 'A' },
  { code: 2001, text: 'B' },
  { code: 1, text: 'C' }
]
```

I want to display both the code and the text while showing the options in the dropdown menu, but once selected, I want to only show the code in the selected options. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are [slots](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-slots) for this kind of customization.  You can use the `singleLabel` slot to customize the selected option, and the `option` slot to customize each dropdown option

```html
<multiselect v-model="value" :options="options">
  <template #singleLabel="{ option }">
    <div>{{ option.code }}</div>
  </template>
  <template #option="{ option }">
    <div>{{ option.code }} - {{ option.text }}</div>
  </template>
</multiselect>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your are looking for something like this.

```
<v-select
  :items="options"
  :item-title="(item)=>`${item.code} = ${item.text}`"
  :item-value="(item)=>`${item.code}`"
  label="Select"
  multiple
>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
    {{ item.value }}
  </template>
</v-select>
```

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)